# How to show sample size based on date chosen by the user from slicer?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

My goal is to display random sample from large volume which is a certain percentage per day selected in the slicer.

To do this I created random number for every line and set up ranking measure using RANX function:

`Rank`*Processed Rank = RANKX(ALLSELECTED(A),FIRSTNONBLANK(A[Random Number], [Random Number]))*

Than I created another measure which should work as limiter:

`My Limiter`*Selected N = VAR Volume = COUNT(A[Distinct Number])
VAR SampleSize =ROUNDUP(Volume * 0.1 * 0.4, 0)
RETURN SampleSize*

In last step I set up third measure using simple IF which I want to use as filter in displayed Table:

`Filter`*Processed Rank within Selected N = IF([Processed Rank] <= [Selected N], 1, 0)*

The filter for Processed Rank within Selected N should display only lines equal to 1.

The solution as it is right now doesn't work cause Selected N equals 1 for every line in the table but when I display Selected N as a Card it shows what I need.

For example:
User selects particular date.
Volume for this day is 1117. Selected N in the table is 1 for every line but card with Selected N shows 45 as it should.

How can I make Selected N 45 for every line in the table in my example so that when I apply filter using

`Filter`*Processed Rank within Selected N = IF([Processed Rank] <= [Selected N], 1, 0)** it will work?

[filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jpyA.png)